# Azure AKS auto scale vs. the belonging Scale Set Auto Scale

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

In Azure K8s service, you can scale up the node pool but only we define the min and max nodes.
When i check the node pool scale set scale settings, i found it set to manual.
So i assume that the Node Pool auto scale does't rely on the belonging scale set, but i wonder, can we just rely on the scale set auto scale with the several metric roles instead of the very limited Node Pool scale settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AKS autoscaling works slightly different as the VMSS autoscaling.

From the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler):

> The cluster autoscaler watches for pods that can't be scheduled on
> nodes because of resource constraints. The cluster then automatically
> increases the number of nodes.

The AKS autoscaler is tightly coupled with the control plane and the kube-scheduler, so it takes resource requests and limits into account that is far the better scaling method as the VMSS autoscaler (for k8s workload) that is anyway not supported for AKS:

> The cluster autoscaler is a Kubernetes component. Although the AKS
> cluster uses a virtual machine scale set for the nodes, don't manually
> enable or edit settings for scale set autoscale in the Azure portal or
> using the Azure CLI.